# Does anyone know what type of structure this is?

Tags: ancient-rome, architecture, classical-antiquity

I came across this picture taken at an ancient Roman site (name & location not provided) and was wondering what kind of structure it is. I've searched for fountains, wells, milestones, and memorials, but was not able to find anything similar to this one. Would appreciate it if someone knows what it is and how it was used! Plus I'd like to know if there's a Latin name for it. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Do you have any other pictures from other sides?  I am sort of thinking it is a fountain because of the basin, but your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Definitely looks like a fountain, with a vertical grove for the water pipe, and surrounding basin.

Comment: looks like: http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Monument_(Civ6)
maybe it was to give cultural bonuses? :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a roman fountain at Djemila, Algeria (Latin: Cuicul or Curculum). There's a vast amount of literature and web material on Djemila in general (and some on the fountain), for example:

- The Princeton Encyclopedia of Classical Sites (Richard Stillwell et al), on [Cuicul in general](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0006:id=cuicul)
- [Cuicul: New/Severian Town](https://www.romeartlover.it/Djemila2.html)
- The french [Wikipedia article on Djemila](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djemila) is quite comprehensive and has a section about the fountain
- William Lloyd MacDonald, [The Architecture of the Roman Empire](https://books.google.de/books?id=XJrTBa4p4sIC&lpg=PA13&ots=DcwPO3Euku&dq=roman%20fountain%20Djemila&hl=de&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=roman%20fountain%20Djemila&f=false)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, very informative!

Comment: FYI, "literature" is uncountable, so "vast number of literature" is grammatically incorrect. "Vast *amount* of literature" would work. "Vast" is also not usually paired with a countable phrase (though I'm unsure if it's incorrect). To make "web sources" fit into the uncountable phrase, you might try something like "web material" (but I'm sure there's a better phrase than that).

Comment: @jpmc26: Thank you for your hints - i've edited my answer. SInce i'm not a native speaker, it's quite likely that there are some errors in my english texts...

Comment: The site is also famous for French writer Albert Camus' essay "Le Vent à Djemila", written in 1939: http://tangodelviudo.blogspot.com/2012/11/the-wind-at-djemila.html